# Go "cannot find package"

Tags: go, go-modules

I have a public repository https://github.com/zhksoftGo/Packet. I have put some common go files in it.
Currently, there are two.

```
 Packet.go under github.com/zhksoftGo/Packet
 TypeDefineCactus.go under github.com/zhksoftGo/Packet/protocol/Cactus/
```

I meet trouble at importing one of them.

```
import "github.com/zhksoftGo/Packet"   // works fine
import "github.com/zhksoftGo/Packet/protocol/Cactus" // "cannot find package"
```

//referer project .mod file:

```
module github.com/zhksoftGo/SnowWolf

go 1.15

require (
    github.com/gookit/slog v0.1.3
    github.com/panjf2000/gnet v1.4.2
    github.com/smartystreets/goconvey v1.6.4 // indirect
    github.com/zhksoftGo/Packet v0.0.0-20210320131229-5311a044e61f
    gopkg.in/ini.v1 v1.62.0
)
```

I have already set GO111MODULE=on. Could somebody help on this?

Comment: Can you try adding ```replace github.com/zhksoftGo/Packet => /absoule/path/to/your/project``` to your go.mod file, tidy with `go mod tidy` and building again?

Comment: I have tried the replace, same error.

Comment: I've tried and i see no problem
https://github.com/alessiosavi/StackOverflow/blob/master/Go/66742528/main.go

Comment: @zhk_tiger try upgrading the module on your machine, run `go get -u github.com/zhksoftGo/Packet@latest` and do that inside the `github.com/zhksoftGo/SnowWolf` project so that the command also updates the reference in the go.mod file.

Comment: @alessiosavi Yes, it works in your test. And also works if put main.go in a sub folder.
Works for Main1, but same issue for Main2.
https://github.com/zhksoftGo/Snow

Comment: @mkopriva It has no effect.

Comment: @zhk_tiger your generator is inserting [`<U+FEFF>`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) (not visible) at the [beginning of the file](https://github.com/zhksoftGo/Snow/blob/master/protocol_snowwolf/CocAssist/TypeDefineCocAssist.go#L1) which breaks the whole package.

Comment: @zhk_tiger this is how the file looks when I open it in vim: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/lE7dB9f). After removing the zero-width-space character the package is found by `go build`, although the program still doesn't compile because many of the fields are referenced without prefixing them with the receiver, e.g. [`mType.Write(pak)`](https://github.com/zhksoftGo/Snow/blob/master/protocol_snowwolf/CocAssist/TypeDefineCocAssist.go#L66) should be `v.mType.Write(pak)`, once you fix those errors your Main2 will compile.

Comment: @mkopriva Yeah! It is the reason. This issue confused me several days, you saved my ass. Thanks! The Go error hint needs improvement. I am a c/cpp programmer, just learning Go recently. The Go is really special.

Answer (score 1):

The root reason is my generator inserts utf-8 BOM chars in the generated Go file header. It works if a normal Go file import a generated Go file. But does not work if the generated Go file has another generated Go file imported.
So for Go source file, we'd better use UTF-8.